# JMeter slaves are not reading property file values

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am running jmeter distributed test. I have lot of combinations to test, so created property files (.properties) to execute different tests.

**For example:** 
I have 1 master and 2 slave machines. I have kept jmx script in master machine and test data in all slaves

1. Started jmeter-server in all slave machines
2. Ran distributed test from master with following command
   **"jmeter -n -t script.jmx -p condition1.properties -R SlaveIP1,SlaveIP1 -l results.jtl"**

**Results**: 
Test runs well but with default values defined in script. In my case test duration defined in script is 300 secs whereas test duration in condition1.properties file is defined as 900, but test always runs for 300 seconds.

This is just an example, I have many other parameters defined in property file and should be picked up while running the test.

This problem is happening only in case of master & slave condition, otherwise running test from single machine picks up all values defined in property file.

Answer (score 0):

According [JMeter list of command-line options](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) you can't use -p in the case of disturbed testing, but use -G instead.

```
  -G, --globalproperty <argument>=<value>
        Define Global properties (sent to servers)
        e.g. -Gport=123
         or -Gglobal.properties
```